# Delete lines from cursor to end of file

Tags: sublime-text-2

with sublime text, I can delete from cursor to end of line with

```
super+k-k
```

how I can delete from cursor to the end of file ?

Answer (score 14):

No need to write a script. Simply highlight the first line you want to delete, then:

```
Ctrl+Shift+End
```

This will select all the text until the end of the file. Then just press `delete`!

This works in many different programs. Not just sublime Text.

Comment: Use `Cmd+Shift+down` if you're on mac

Answer (score 1):

It's not too hard, but you'll have to create a macro and a custom key binding to do it. First, create a new file with the following contents:

```json
[
    {"command": "move_to", "args": {"to": "eof", "extend": true}},
    {"command": "add_to_kill_ring", "args": {"forward": true}},
    {"command": "right_delete"}
]
```

Save the file as `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/User/Delete to EOF.sublime-macro`. You can access the `Packages` folder by going to `Sublime Text 2 -> Preferences -> Browse Packages...` - this will open up a new Finder window in the right directory.

Next, go to `Sublime Text 2 -> Preferences -> Key Bindings - User`. If you haven't made any custom key bindings before, this file will be empty, otherwise it will contain previous key bindings. If it is empty, paste the following into it and save:

```json
[
    { "keys": ["super+k", "super+f"], "command": "run_macro_file", "args": {"file": "Packages/User/Delete to EOF.sublime-macro"} }
]
```

Make sure the value for `"file":` is exactly the same name as the macro file you just created. If you already have custom key bindings, simply copy the middle line (leave out the square brackets on the first and last lines) and paste it at the beginning of your key bindings file, on a line just after the opening bracket `[`. Make sure you add a comma `,` at the end of the line:

```json
[
    { "keys": ["super+k", "super+f"], "command": "run_macro_file", "args": {"file": "Packages/User/Delete to EOF.sublime-macro"} },
    // existing key bindings...
]
```

Save the file, and you should now be able to hit <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>,<kbd>Command ⌘</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> and delete to the end of the file.